# Missing command prompt user name when a user account is created - Linux - Debian?

Tags: linux, bash, debian

I am writing a bash script to create user account with password, that will expire. After creating the user account and then login using su - , I get the prompt, but the user id is missing in the prompt. Also, the tab auto complete is missing. Here is my bash script. Remember, I am using Debian 9 in Windows - WSL2.

```
#!/bin/bash

# This script creates an account on the local system.
# You will be prompted for the account name and password.

# Ask for the user name.
read -p 'Enter the username to create: ' USER_NAME

# Ask for the real name.
read -p 'Enter the name of the person who this account is for: ' COMMENT

# Ask for the password
read -p 'Enter the password to use for the account: ' PASSWORD

# Create the user 
useradd -c "${COMMENT}" -m ${USER_NAME}

# Set the password for the user.
# echo ${PASSWORD} | passwd --stdin ${USER_NAME}

echo "${USER_NAME}:${PASSWORD}" | chpasswd

# Force password change on first login.
passwd -e ${USER_NAME}
```

After running this, I get a prompt which doesn't has a user-id in it on the left side. Also, the auto completion using tab isn't working. I am a bit surprised, am I doing something wrong here?

Here is what I am seeing.

[image]

Comment: The `'-'` in `su -` *"clears all the environment variables except TERM and variables specified by `--whitelist-environment`"* (that would include `PS1` prompt)

Answer (score 0):

Add a user with adduser command instead of useradd.
Inscript always user adduser.
tested the same script on the Debian box and it's working fine.